# No DefaultLifecycleObserver callback when using work manger OnDemand initialization

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I need to observe application lifecycle to hen app goes to background and comes to foreground but since I added the OnDemand initialization for the workmanger the callbacks for DefaultLifecycleObserver  does not work anymore.

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

If i remove above line it works well but then Worker cannot be initialize.
I'm using JAVA 8 and hilt for dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [custom WorkManager configuration guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration), you can disable WorkManager initialization while keeping any other App Startup components that don't depend on WorkManager:

```xml
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```